# Enable php module on nitrous.io

Tags: php, curl, nitrousio

Currently my project need curl extension for php. It is shown that nitrousio's php5 is compiled with curl from https://github.com/nitrous-io/autoparts/blob/master/lib/autoparts/packages/php5.rb. 
But when I check extension_loaded('curl'), the return value is false. How can I enable this module? And my project also need gd with FreeType Support, is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Well, what have you already done in order to try to install it? It's more likely someone will be able to tell you what you're doing wrong if you explain what it is that you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

cURL has now been added to php so you can do the following in the boxes terminal to make it work:

```
parts install php5
parts stop apache2
parts start apache2
```